# How to ORDER BY a SUM() in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table: "ID name c_counts f_counts "

and I want to order all the record by `sum(c_counts+f_counts)`
but this doesn't work:

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY sum(c_counts+f_counts) LIMIT 20;`

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Don'y forget that if you are mixing grouped (ie. SUM) fields and non-grouped fields, you need to GROUP BY one of the non-grouped fields.

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(something) AS fieldname
FROM tablename
ORDER BY fieldname
```

OR this:

```
SELECT Field1, SUM(something) AS Field2
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Field1
ORDER BY Field2
```

And you can always do a derived query like this:

```
SELECT
   f1, f2
FROM
    (
        SELECT SUM(x+y) as f1, foo as F2
        FROM tablename 
        GROUP BY f2
    ) as table1
ORDER BY 
    f1
```

Many possibilities!

Comment: yes, I wanna order all records by the sum of some fields.
this works:
SELECT sum(c_counts+f_counts) FROM table GROUP BY name LIMIET 20;
thank you!

Comment: You my friend just made my life a hell of a lot easier! Been struggling with a similar query for ages and couldn't quite get it right - you just saved my bacon! Thanks very much!

Comment: you can also SELECT field1, sum(field) from table order by 2 (where 2 means basically the second field), it is convenient in interactive use, but I wouldn't recommend it for actual code.

Answer (score 9):

This is how you do it

```
SELECT ID,NAME, (C_COUNTS+F_COUNTS) AS SUM_COUNTS 
FROM TABLE 
ORDER BY SUM_COUNTS LIMIT 20
```

The SUM function will add up all rows, so the `order by` clause is useless, instead you will have to use the `group by` clause.

Comment: this will indeed work to sort by the sum of those two fields.  I was reading "sum" as the aggregate function "sum", but I think you have the correct interpretation here.

Answer (score 7):

You could try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY (c_counts+f_counts) 
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Very useful when we have a `getBy(order)` function that calls SQL, we can do something like that: `getBy("(c_counts+f_counts)")`

Answer (score 0):

Without a GROUP BY clause, any summation will roll all rows up into a single row, so your query will indeed not work. If you grouped by, say, name, and ordered by sum(c_counts+f_counts), then you might get some useful results. But you would have to group by something.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see here is that "sum" is an aggregate function.

first, you need to fix the query itself.

```
Select sum(c_counts + f_counts) total, [column to group sums by]
from table
group by [column to group sums by]
```

then, you can sort it:

```
Select *
from (query above) a
order by total
```

EDIT:
But see post by Virat.  Perhaps what you want is not the sum of your total fields over a group, but just the sum of those fields for each record.  In that case, Virat has the right solution.

Comment: The subquery is unnecessary -- simply add an `ORDER BY` to the first query.  In that example: `ORDER BY total` or `ORDER BY total DESC`.  If you need a `LIMIT` also, then it goes afterwards.