# How can order the result , MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with a table 'Posts Table'.

In this table there are posts id, count user comment and count visitors comment.

I want to extra the top posts which have most comments

But the problem is there is two columns for comment (users comment, visitors comment).

I want the result like this , (usercomment + visitors comment) ,

How can I use SQL to do this?

[image]

Comment: Possible repost of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309841/how-to-order-by-a-sum-in-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Posts
ORDER BY UserComments + VisitorComments DESC
```

That ought to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Posts order by UserComments + VisitorComments desc
```

You need the DESC otherwise I believe it defaults to ASC