# MySQL: Sort by group and field

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp, select, sql-order-by

I have a table with the following (simplified) structure:

```
INT id,
INT type,
INT sort
```

What I need is a SELECT that sorts my data in a way, so that:

- all rows of the same type are in sequency, sorted ascendingly by `sort` internally, and
- all "blocks" of one type are sorted by their minimum `sort`.

**Example:**

If the table looks like this:

```
| id | type | sort |
|  1 |   1  |   3  |
|  2 |   3  |   5  |
|  3 |   3  |   1  |
|  4 |   2  |   4  |
|  5 |   1  |   2  |
|  6 |   2  |   6  |
```

The query should sort the result like this:

```
| id | type | sort |
|  3 |   3  |   1  |
|  2 |   3  |   5  | 
|  5 |   1  |   2  |
|  1 |   1  |   3  | 
|  4 |   2  |   4  |
|  6 |   2  |   6  |
```

I hope this makes it clear enough.

Looks to me, as this should be a very common requirement, but I didn't find any examples close enough to be able to transfer it to my use case on my own. I suppose I can't avoid at least one subquery, but I didn't figure it out on my own.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

By the way: I'm going to use this query with CakePHP 2.1, so if you know of a comfortable way to do it with Cake, please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309841/how-to-order-by-a-sum-in-mysql

Comment: Because I'm still fiddling with transfering this to CakePHP, I opened the same question, only Cake-specific here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798183/cakephp-sort-by-group-maximum-minimum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simpler than it initially sounds.  I believe the following should do the trick:

```
SELECT a.id, a.type, a.sort
FROM Some_Table as a
JOIN (SELECT type, MIN(sort) as min
      FROM Some_Table
      GROUP BY type) as b
ON b.type = a.type
ORDER BY b.min, a.type, a.sort
```

For best (fastest) results, you're probably going to want an index on (`type`, `sort`).
You want an additional sort by `a.type` (instead of (`b.min`, `a.sort`)), in case there are two groups with the same `sort` value (would result in mixed rows).  If there are no duplicate values, you can remove it.

Comment: I tested this and it's not working for me however I think you are close. Edit: Actually it seems to be working now.

Comment: Thanks a lot X-Zero! After your edit, this seems to be working fine!

Comment: Sub queries are explained at the bottom of this page http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions

Comment: I still didn't figure out how to do it in cake. I know how to do subqueries and how to do joins, but how would I transfer the 'ON'-statement to cake and how would I bring it all together?

Comment: The `ON` statement is part of a `JOIN` (in DB2, it's required - not sure about elsewhere).  It's specifying your join criteria.  Unfortunately, I have no experience with cakePHP (sorry, I missed that part of the question), so I can't help you with that part.

Comment: Thanks anyway, your answer was still pretty helpful! I didn't get an answer on my CakePHP oriented question here and also not in IRC, so I suppose there really is no easy way to do this cake-like.

Answer (score 0):

sort and type are reserved words on some databases and can cause you problems.

Have you tried?

```
ORDER BY TYPE DESC, SORT ASC
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't get what the OP wants, and doesn't match his desired output.