# Select the first ten rows with the highest values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database that looks like this;
[image: db]

I need a query that can select the first ten rows with the highest values first to the lowest values.

In this case, the first four columns on the fourth row with value **33** should be returned first, followed by the first column of the eleventh row with value **25**, followed by the second column of the third and eleventh rows with value **13**, followed by the first column of the third row with value **12** and the columns from row seven with value **11** until there are up to ten results. Basically I want to order my results by the values in these columns. Thanks!

Comment: Seeing as how you didn't do any of the work to figure it out and just made a request, read this and it should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309841/how-to-order-by-a-sum-in-mysql

Comment: The link you provided was not helpful. And i did a thorough search before asking my question thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-order the rows in your table but not the columns. This is obvious but I wasn't sure if you were asking this.

That said, you have to use the `order by` clause in SQL.

`select * from my_table order by def_w1, def_w2, def_w3, def_w4 desc`

This will order your rows in descending order, starting with comparisons at column1, then column2, then column3, then column4. You can change the `order by` clause to specify a different order of comparisons.

Comment: I want to use the values in the columns to select the corresponding rows.. The values of def_w1,def_w2,def_w3 and so on to choose the rows to return. I have tried the query you suggested, it simply returns all rows ordered. I want the rows with the highest def_w1, or def_w2 or def_w3..and so on.