# MySQL query with SUM and order

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sum

What is wrong with my query? Can somebody help me please?

I get this errormessage

> "Unknown column 'wp_gdsr_data_article.
>   (SUM(user_voters)+SUM(visitor_voters))' in 'order clause'"

but the '`wp_gdsr_data_article`' colum exist

```
    SELECT *
    FROM `wp_posts`
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = ID AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 1
    INNER JOIN wp_gdsr_data_article ON post_id = ID
    WHERE `post_status` = 'publish'
    AND `post_type` = 'post'
    ORDER BY `wp_gdsr_data_article`.`(SUM(user_voters)+SUM(visitor_voters))` DESC
    LIMIT 1 , 30
```

Comment: i thing you code is fine try to **remove your Quotes**,..

Comment: *...but the 'wp_gdsr_data_article' colum exist*. From your SQL query, it does not seem to be a column but table.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an expression in the `ORDER` clause which not a table's column.
Hence you can't use a table identifier on the outcome of an expression.

This is wrong.

```
ORDER BY `wp_gdsr_data_article`.`(SUM(user_voters)+SUM(visitor_voters))` DESC
```

Change it to:

```
ORDER BY (SUM(user_voters)+SUM(visitor_voters)) DESC
```

And you can't directly use any aggregate function in `ORDER BY` clause like that.
Calculate `SUM...` parts separately and then use in `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT * from (
    SELECT *, (SUM(user_voters)+SUM(visitor_voters)) total
    FROM `wp_posts`
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
            ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = ID 
               AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 1
    INNER JOIN wp_gdsr_data_article 
            ON post_id = ID
    WHERE `post_status` = 'publish'
      AND `post_type` = 'post'
    LIMIT 1 , 30
) results
ORDER BY total
```

**Refer to**: [*How to ORDER BY a SUM() in MySQL?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309841/how-to-order-by-a-sum-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes from all columns and tablenames in your statement. Besides the Order by part should base on a column or an evaluated value in our statement, the way you use it is wrong. you will need to evaluate the part which you use in the order by section before using it for the order by, something like this (untested):

```
SELECT (SUM(wp_gdsr_data_article.user_voters)+SUM(wp_gdsr_data_article.visitor_voters) as total_voters), *
FROM wp_posts 
  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships 
     ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = ID 
       AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 1
  INNER JOIN wp_gdsr_data_article 
     ON post_id = ID
WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY total_voters DESC
LIMIT 1 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *, (SUM(wp_gdsr_data_article.user_voters)+SUM(wp_gdsr_data_article.visitor_voters)) AS someSum
FROM `wp_posts`
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = ID AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 1
INNER JOIN wp_gdsr_data_article ON post_id = ID
WHERE `post_status` = 'publish'
AND `post_type` = 'post'
ORDER BY someSum DESC
LIMIT 1 , 30
```

Comment: This wont get compiled.

Comment: corrected now. assuming `user_voters` is a column of `wp_gdsr_data_article`