# How to get sum of column for different values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like the one below.

```
a1    |    a2  |  a3

Mike       3      Sam
Mike       3      John
John       2      Sam
John       1      Alex
Alex       3      Mike
Alex       2      Sam
Alex       3      John
```

I need to get a result like this:

```
Mike =3+3 = 6
John =2+1 = 3
Alex= 3+2+3 =8

SELECT sum (a2) from table1 WHERE a1 in (SELECT a1 FROM table1)
```

Comment: `SELECT a1, SUM(a2) FROM table GROUP BY a1`

Answer (score 3):

It's an easy SQL Query.

```
SELECT a1, SUM(a2)
FROM table
GROUP BY a1;
```

Answer (score 1):

For your example add simply the `group by a1` clause to the sql stmt.

```
SELECT a1, sum (a2)
from table1 
WHERE a1 in (SELECT a1 FROM table1)
GROUP BY a1;
```

But you can also omit the where clause because its redundant, so 
the final code looks like this:

```
SELECT a1, sum (a2)
from table1 
GROUP BY a1;
```

> When combining with the GROUP BY clause, the SUM function calculates
>   the sum for every group specified in the GROUP BY clause.

See these references:

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

See also these answer to the question:

[How to ORDER BY a SUM() in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309841/how-to-order-by-a-sum-in-mysql)

Comment: just an fyi posting links and non coded examples that help out in answering the issue and or question at hand will expose your reputation points to `negative` hits I didn't downvote your question btw but normally things like that should be posted as comments..

Comment: @MethodMan yes you are right first time i added no code -.- i edit my answer now

Comment: I changed my vote, the reason I downvoted was outlined by @MethodMan.