# Sum row contents from a joined table

Tags: php, mysql, join, sum

I have two tables here.

- `log` (stands for logbook)
- `act` (stands for actions)

**log**

contains columns: `logid`, `userid`, `actid`

**act**

contains columns: `actid`, `amount`

Amount stands for an amount of points (e.g. 50 of 700 or 5) the user (`userid`) receives when the corresponding `actid` is inserted in the logbook (`log`).

What I'm trying to achieve is that when you search for `userid` 1, that all rows from `log` where `userid = 1` are selected. Then, from these selected `log`-rows, the `actid`s should be looked up in the table `act`, and the `amount`s should be summed.

In short:

- select `log`-rows where `userid = 1`
- take all the `actids` from these rows
- find the matching `amount` in the `act` table
- sum all these `amounts`

I started with this query:

```
SELECT log.logid, log.userid, log.actid, act.actid, act.amount
FROM log
    JOIN act
        ON act.actid = log.actid
WHERE log.userid = '1'
```

This got me a table with (among other things)

**userid | amount**

---1----|--20---

---1----|--40---

---1----|---5---

---1----|--10---

Now I would like to `sum` all these amounts and echo the total, but unfortunately I can't find a working query for this.

**EDIT:**

I used the query that Naruto provided me to sum these amounts. This works like a charm now! The query:

```
SELECT log.userid, sum(act.amount) FROM log JOIN act ON act.actid = log.actid WHERE log.userid = '1'
```

The next thing that I'm trying is to get not only the summed amount from the user with `userid = 1`, but also from the other users in the `user`-table. After that, I'd like to use these summed amounts in the following query:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `db`.`user` ORDER BY `summed_amount` DESC");
```

In which `summed_amount` is the summed amount generated by Naruto's query.

Comment: Your update is a separate question but it's a duplicate. [Check this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309841/how-to-order-by-a-sum-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has an Aggregate function called sum() which can sum all the records.

So your query will be

```
SELECT log.userid, sum(act.amount) FROM log JOIN act ON act.actid = log.actid WHERE log.userid = '1'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum

Comment: What would you do to echo this summed amount with the least unnecessary code? First, I put it like this: $result = $mysqli->query( {here goes your query } ). But then what, use mysqli_fetch_assoc()? Or is there a better way?

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc() is appropriate for it. Please mark the solution as ACCEPTED if your problem is solved.In this way it will help others looking for similar problem

Comment: Thank you very much, Naruto! I added an extra question to the end of my post, could you please take a look and let me know if the thing I'm trying to achieve is possible?

Comment: Your query is a bit confusing.. tell me what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: Your query worked to make it possible to echo the summed amount for log.userid = '1' on my page. Now, I'd like to do thesame for the other users in the user-table, using a while loop. So that I have a summed amount for every user. Then I'd like to echo a table with the userid and the summed amount for each userid, ORDERed BY the summed amount DESC.

Comment: To find the summed value, run the same query again without where clause filter.

SELECT  sum(act.amount) from act

Comment: Without the where clause filter, it just sums up the amounts from all userid-s for userid 1, instead of giving a different summed amount for every userid.

Comment: Please check another answer i just added to solve your problem. Please mark solution as ACCEPTED if your problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

To get sum of all users by a single query use group by clause.Here it will calculate sum of amaount for each user and return the result.

```
SELECT log.userid, sum(act.amount) FROM log JOIN act ON act.actid = log.actid group by log.userid
```

Edit:- To get order by desc

SELECT log.userid, sum(act.amount) FROM log JOIN act ON act.actid = log.actid group by log.userid order by sum(act.amount) desc

Comment: Is it possible to use these sums in an ORDER BY clause to echo all userid-s with their own sum, ordered by the sums DESC?

Comment: yes you can add order by clause to get result in descending order by sum

Comment: Please mark the solution as ACCEPTED if your problem is solved.In this way it will help others looking for similar problem

Comment: I simplified the situation for a bit in my first post, but now I edited your second query to my actual situation (with another table to join) and I'm so happy it works. Thank you very much!