# sum as a window function produces weird results

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Consider the following query in PostgreSQL:

```sql
select x, sum(x) over (order by x)
from (
    select 1 x
    from generate_series(1, 5)
    union all
    select generate_series(1, 5) x
) q
```

I would expect the results to be the following:

```
x       | sum
integer | bigint
--------+-------
      1 |     1
      1 |     2
      1 |     3
      1 |     4
      1 |     5
      1 |     6
      2 |     8
      3 |    11
      4 |    15
      5 |    20
```

But instead I'm getting this:

```
x       | sum
integer | bigint
--------+-------
      1 |     6
      1 |     6
      1 |     6
      1 |     6
      1 |     6
      1 |     6
      2 |     8
      3 |    11
      4 |    15
      5 |    20
```

Could this be how `sum` is expected to behave, not only in PostgreSQL, but in other RDBMSs that support using `sum` as a window function?

It seems the issue here is that it won't maintain a running total across a set of adjacent rows that are equal with respect to ordering criteria. But could that really be intended behaviour or just a bug?

Here's a workaround, but it doesn't seem right that it should be necessary:

```
select x, sum(x) over (order by rn)
from (
    select x, row_number() over (order by x) rn
    from (
        select 1 x
        from generate_series(1, 5)
        union all
        select generate_series(1, 5) x
    ) q
) r
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309841/how-to-order-by-a-sum-in-mysql Maybe this could help

Comment: The ordering of the rows themselves is not the issue. It's what the database is doing with the ordering with respect to some window functions. For example, `row_number` won't produce equal values between rows in the same partition whereas functions like `rank` and `dense_rank` will. It seems that `sum` is behaving like the latter and yet the most common use case for `sum` as a window function would surely be to show a running total. (In reply to a now deleted comment.)

Comment: Will the downvoter kindly explain how this question does not show any research effort and is unclear or not useful?

Comment: Btw: why are you writing the constant `1` so complicated in the first part?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm open to a simpler way of emitting 5 repetitions of `1`.

Comment: `select 1 from generate_series(1, 5)`

Comment: So simple! Thanks. Question updated.